# mongo db get data from two tables using same id

Tags: mongodb

i have two tables `history` and `jobs`
my history table contains

```
> db.history.find()
{ "id" : "21", "browser" : "FF","os" : "Windows" "datetime" : "2013-11-26 17:04:21", "_id" : ObjectId("5294873d6b441e2c16000002") }

 db.jobs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5289c147db9ed2b022f95a36"),  "id" : "21", "launch" : "ertret", "names" : "234",  "script" : "art-pagination" }
```

From the above two tables i need to get `browser`, `launch`, `script` and `os` by using common `id: 21`
How it is possible.

Comment: It's not named table, but collection in MongoDB =P

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using following two queries. It is not possible to get it with single query.

```
> db.history.find({'id':21}, {'browser':1, 'os':1})

> db.jobs.find({'id':21}, {'launch':1,'script':1 })
```